# Preserve look of code and comments in installed R code?

Tags: r, function, r-package

When printing an R-function defined in the global workspace you get it as-is, e.g.

```
test <- function(x) {
    ## some comment
    ifelse(test = x != 0,
           yes = ifelse(test = x < 0,
                        yes = "negative",
                        no = "positive"),
           no = "zero")
}
```

will print with in the way it was written. If the same function `test` is included in a package (I'm using `devtools::install` for installation) then printing it looks like

```
> print(test)
function (x) 
{
    ifelse(test = x != 0, yes = ifelse(test = x < 0, yes = "negative", 
        no = "positive"), no = "zero")
}
<bytecode: 0x000001bb6b02b040>
<environment: namespace:myTestPackage>
```

which is harder to read and the comment is gone. Is there any way to control what the formatting of installed code looks like (in particular keep it as-is) and/or keep comments? (Intended use is personal only. Also, I understand that somewhat better printing can be achieved via e.g. `formatR::tidy_source`.)

Comment: When you install a package, the code is compiled into an RDS file. The original source isn't preserved since that would basically double the size of the package. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by preserving code formatting in a package? Usually people make the source code available on github or something if people want to view the source for functions in a package in the original form.

Comment: @MrFlick : Code is actually intended for small number of people, most of whom are not used to creating packages/using github. It would be nice to be able to get a very readably version of the source code without having to find it within a package structure "somewhere else". But certainly work-arounds are possible.

Comment: With R package, the assumption is that you would include relevant details for uses of your package in the documentation for the package, not in the source code of the functions themselves.  Functions in the source are only for developers and it's assumed that developers would be using some sort of external source control system.  If preserving source code comments its a requirements, an R package probably isn't the right thing for you. But for most other uses, R packages are the best way to share code.

Comment: Yes, that is a fair point. Comments are actually not the main interest, it is easy access to very readable source code. I don't know much about the internal workings of package installation, so at the outset it didn't seem impossible that there could have been some way to keep the source in some fashion. If that isn't the case, then I guess educating the users about github and/or making a wrapper for `tidy_source` with suitable arguments are ways forward.